# How many results to search for with Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

In my application I'm using Lucene (4.8) as search engine.

I use the IndexSearcher to determine *10* docIds and after that I load the complete *10* documents from my database. While using the following method, my question is: **How big should *n* be?**

```
search(Query query, Filter filter, int n, Sort sort)
```

The application also supports paging so theoretically *n* could be *Integer.MAX_VALUE* and after the search I determine the *10* docIds I want and so on...

**But is this a good way?**

I mean if there's a possibility to specify an offset I could do the paging in this step and end the search process after getting *10* docs.

So finally: **Would it be a massive speedup to just search for 10 instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE docs?**

P.S. I can't test the last question on my own because my database isn't that big to see any difference... but it will be much bigger when it's live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, even if you specify `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it will be rounded down to the max doc id - there's no point searching above the maximum absolute limit.

Regarding speedup - nobody will give give you precise answers because each index is different. There are some common points though.

- for each search, new `Object[size]` is allocated for results (`org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue:64` - that's Lucene version 4.9.0, line number can vary across versions)
- There's also another allocation at `org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher:467` where `ScoreDoc` array is initialized with the (same?) number.
- And obviously there's a CPU & I/O cost of setting each of these array elements

Even if initializing each of these search results would be cheap, for large index it would add up. Also there's a price to pay for garbage collection of these large blocks. Imagine if you are running search 10 times a second, and are getting 1M search results. That's a lot of work for GC! So if you can do something to trim the search results - do it.

However the above advice (as well as any other) only makes sense outside of your context. Measure, don't guess! Trimming is an optimization which can be left for later -- if you can afford it.

Comment: So for now I'm satisfied with using the max number of docs instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE... (sometimes I'm just afraid to use this big number :D)
And you are also right with your last sentence. For now we can afford that and will look at it later.

Comment: This is most likely because your index is small. For larger index, this *may* have more impact.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to return all the hits for each page of 10.

You can use the `searchAfter` method (see [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#searchAfter%28org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int%29)), which is more appropriate for your search.